# Getting the following error “IndexError: list index out of range” in YahooEarningsCalendar class

Tags: python

I don't know how to solve the following error that arises from executing a few simple lines associated with Yahoo! Earnings Calendar scraper. Thanks!

```
# setting the report date
report_date = datetime.now().date()

# downloading the earnings calendar
yec = YahooEarningsCalendar()
earnings_list = yec.earnings_on(report_date)

# saving the data in a pandas DataFrame
earnings_df = pd.DataFrame(earnings_list)
earnings_df.head()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-572b320df252>", line 6, in <module>
    earnings_list = yec.earnings_on(report_date)

  File "C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\yahoo_earnings_calendar\scraper.py", line 93, in earnings_on
    page_data_dict = self._get_data_dict(dated_url)

  File "C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\yahoo_earnings_calendar\scraper.py", line 39, in _get_data_dict
    '\n') if row.startswith('root.App.main = ')][0][:-1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```